# Transferring the project to another server, with all the data in apex oracl

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to migrate the project to another server, I exported the project, and generated for all the tables. But I can't migrate these tables. Someone can help me with this. ????

Comment: What do you mean by "But I can't migrate these tables?" Are you getting an error? Are you talking about the application metadata or the data in a custom schema that the APEX app works with?

Comment: I mean that I can migrate tables and applications, but I can not move tables data. For example, I have a table with users, I want to move a table together with a list of all users, so as not to enter them manually!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I'd say your best bet to migrate any custom schemas is to use Data Pump. Data Pump is made up of three distinct components. They are the command-line clients, expdp and impdp; the DBMS_DATAPUMP PL/SQL package (also known as the Data Pump API); and the DBMS_METADATA PL/SQL package (also known as the Metadata API).

An example export would look like:

```
expdp hr TABLES=employees DUMPFILE=employees.dmp
```

That would generate a file you could move to the destination database (where a database directory can map to).

Then an example import would look like:

```
impdp hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=employees.dmp TABLES=employees
```

Of course, there are many more options than that. Here's the official doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/index.html

Also, if you want to move to Oracle's [new always free tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/?source=:ow:o:p:nav:0916BCButton&intcmp=:ow:o:p:nav:0916BCButton), then Adrian Png provides a nice overview that also touches on some APEX related topics here:
https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1920/